# c# Crystal Report add sub report to a section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to add a sub report to a section dynamically. Is there a way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a ReportDocument object, you can use the ReportClientDocument-API to add a new subreport like this (example for page footer):

`report.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("Test", @"C:\test-sub.rpt", report.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.PageFooterArea.Sections[0], left, top, width, height);`

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I need to add the same report with different data populated. And the data has to be passed dynamically. So I can not use a physical path as ur solution. Is there a way to do it dynamically other than giving a physical path to an existing report.